# Date Formatting and filtering in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to convert "Mon Oct 12 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)" date format to "YYYY/MM/DD" in my controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do this in this way:

```
var date = "Mon Oct 12 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)";

var newDate = $filter('date')(new Date(date), 'yyyy/MM/dd');
```

[Angular date](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)